# How can I get certain mobile numbers from contact list?

Tags: android, contacts

I have an app that has to show my phone contact list. But how can I get some mobile numbers (that I want)?

Comment: what type of numbers you want to display?

Answer (score 2):

For your example 6XXXXXXX type of number, here is a query to get that type of numbers only.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor contacts = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '"
                        + " 6 " + "%' ", null, "UPPER("
                        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Working for me :

```
 Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {

        String Number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        }
```

Add a permisson to app manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: it will give you all numbers and he wants some specific contact not all contact numbers.